# uiimagepicker crash when calling takepicture method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using custom camera with the help of `UIImagePickerController`. I am subclassing the `UIImagePickerController` class and using without present/dismiss. We are just opening the customise camera view and taking picture. After sometime by clicking camera takepicture method gets called and app is getting crash. No delegate method called during this. My code is this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear] && self.camType==2)
    {
        self.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        self.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear;
        self.showsCameraControls = NO;
        self.wantsFullScreenLayout=NO;
        self.navigationBar.hidden=NO;
        self.cameraOverlayView = mainView;

        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
        self.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [notAllowBtn setHidden:TRUE];
        [cmView setHidden:TRUE];
    }

    self.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:cmView];
}

-(void)cameraTakePic {

    if([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear]) {
        [self takePicture];
    }
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info{
  if (![info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]) {

        NSArray *arr=[[appDel navController] viewControllers];
        id obj=[arr lastObject];
        UIViewController *objContr=((UIViewController *)obj);

        objContr.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [clickBtn setEnabled:YES];

        return;
    }


    UIImage* image = nil;
    UIImage *imageTemp = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

Comment: what's the exception it is showing when it is crashed?

Comment: exception:  setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)

Answer (score 1):

From the Apple `UIImagePickerController` class reference:

> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This
>   class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.
>   The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified,
>   with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the
>   cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional
>   information or manage the interactions between the camera interface
>   and your code.

You shouldn't subclass the `UIImagePickerController` class, instead you should use AVFoundation and make your custom capture methods.

Comment: yes we are assigning a custom view to the cameraoverlayview. i am not able to understand why it is crashig after a lot of use not frequently.

Comment: But you are still subclassing `UIImagePickerController`. That's not going to work.

Comment: please suggest something to overcome with this issue

Comment: @vishwaroopa You must use `AVFoundation` and the methods in there to init your own camera capture view.